# Optional Parameters: "empty" vs "not provided"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, default-parameters

Is there a way to differentiate between an empty value and one that is not mentioned at all?

For example, I'd like to the client to be able to update a Profile and only affect values which are specified in the request... EVEN empty/null ones.

so given a profile with name="Sherlok" and Birthdate="January 6":

```
POST api/profiles/update?name=Sherlock >> only modifies name

POST api/profiles/update?birthdate=&name=Sherlock >> modifies name AND clears birthdate
```

Is there a way to differentiate between the birthdate parameter in those two situations, or do I need to resort to magic values?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually quite a few ways to do this.

1. As @Badri suggested, you can use the `Request` object directly in your actions. This is a very straightforward and simple approach but mixes controller logic with formatting/binding logic. If you want to create a better separation of concerns, try one of the following.
2. There are a number of [parameter binding mechanisms](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) you can choose from. Looks to me like a custom model binder could work well in this case. You can access the `Request` object in the model binder and use something similar to @Badri's code to set up the values you expect (`String.Empty` or `null`) before they get passed to your action.
3. A value provider for the birthdate field might be a better option. You're passing a string that can ultimately be converted to a DateTime object. If you specify that that parameter should use a custom value provider (such as an `IntuitiveDateTimeValueProvider`), you can actually change the type of the parameter in your action to `DateTime` or `Nullable<DateTime>` (`DateTime?`) and let the value provider fill the value appropriately. You can also use a similar strategy for simpler strings for which you want to differentiate between empty and null (e.g., `ExistenceTestingStringValueProvider`).
4. Create additional routes/actions. This isn't a good option if there are a lot of parameters because there are just too many possible combinations, but if there are just a few, this is a very simple solution. One way to do this is to simply create method overloads for each combination. If an overload that only has `name` is hit, it means `birthdate` wasn't specified, but if an overload with both parameters was hit, it means that `birthdate` was specified, even if its value is `null`, giving you a way to distinguish between specified but empty parameter values and unspecified parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ASP.NET Web API binding, it is not possible. Say, you have a DTO class and use it for binding like this.

```
public class MyDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public void Update([FromUri]MyDto dto) { }
```

When you leave out `BirthDate` or have it in the query string with an empty value, it is basically the same and `BirthDate` property will be null in both cases. However, you can read the query string yourself like this.

```
string qs = Request.RequestUri.Query.Substring(1); // leave out ?
var pairs = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(qs);
```

In this case, `pairs["BirthDate"]` will be null, if you leave out the field from the query string (?name=Sherlock).

If you have it in the query string with an empty value (?birthdate=&name=Sherlock), then `pairs["BirthDate"]` will be empty string ("").